# How can some guys discern all parts of a MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor, die

Today, when I was searching for find some dies, I saw these pictures:

[image: die1]

[image: atmega169p]

[image: die2]

Now I'm curious that know how can some guys discern all part of a MCU?
Is there any points that I use those to discern all part of a MCU?
they can discern RAM, FLASH, Clock generator unit and etc...

refrence of picturess:

http://blog.ioactive.com/2007_11_01_archive.html

http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1255032

http://www.mdpi.com/2079-9268/1/1/109/htm

Comment: http://zeptobars.ru/en/

Comment: Apparently only *some* guys can do this, no women allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Memory will be a regular array, and sometimes you can guess a larger block like a A/D.  However, usually the way the people that make these pictures know which sections are what is because they designed the chip.

Comment: Thanks Olin for reply. I have an idea. In your opinion, is it Wisely to say that each unit is near to a pin, that pins related to that part? for example if a unit is near to some A/D pins thus that unit is A/D

Comment: @Roh: Yes, that can be a clue.  Note "clue", as apposed to definative answer.

Comment: Knowing relative sizes of structures and other microarchitectural details can also provide clues. Also, having one die photo labeled by the designer helps in interpreting similar design features. As noted, location relative to pins and edges and relative to other features also gives clues (minimizing communication distance and power/heat distribution are design considerations).